# jquery class change color transition

Tags: jquery, css, colors, background, transition

I am trying to make on login form background color (gradient) change using css classess:

```
.smallWindow-info{
  background-color: #339bb9;
  background-image: -khtml-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#5bc0de), to(#339bb9));
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #5bc0de, #339bb9);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #5bc0de, #339bb9);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #5bc0de), color-stop(100%, #339bb9));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #5bc0de, #339bb9);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #5bc0de, #339bb9);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #5bc0de, #339bb9);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#5bc0de', endColorstr='#339bb9', GradientType=0);
}
.smallWindow-warning{
  background-color: #eedc94;
  background-image: -khtml-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#fceec1), to(#eedc94));
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fceec1, #eedc94);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fceec1, #eedc94);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #fceec1), color-stop(100%, #eedc94));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fceec1, #eedc94);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fceec1, #eedc94);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #fceec1, #eedc94);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#fceec1', endColorstr='#eedc94', GradientType=0);
}
```

but id doesnt work please help
here is code. 
http://jsfiddle.net/4JFpa/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use css animation. Just change css classes.

```
.smallWindow-warning{
background-color: #339bb9;
background-image: linear-gradient(  rgba(255,255,255,0.6),  rgba(0,0,0,0.6) );
box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
animation: smallWindow-warning 5s forwards;
}

@keyframes smallWindow-warning {
100% {background-color: #eedc94;}
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4JFpa/17/)

Comment: This looks promising. I will check. Thanks

Comment: I've tried, but id dosnt work at all for gradient background. Or I am missing something? Check here: http://jsfiddle.net/9CgcN/

Comment: Sorry but you can't animate css background gradients. Im animating background color. You could try add several gradients and then animate background position.

Comment: This is the closest solution to my problem. Thanks man. It is great.

Answer (score 0):

Try this : You need to pass class name (both to remove / add ) in quotes. And remove info class after animation finished, then add warning class and start animation.

[API Doc for animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $( "#loginPanel").animate({
    opacity: 0
  }, 3000, function() {
      $(this).removeClass('smallWindow-info').addClass('smallWindow-warning').animate({ opacity: 1 }, 3000);
  });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4JFpa/10/)**

Comment: Good solution, but it cause that my whole form disapear for a sec. Can it be done without i=disapearing?

Comment: that you can manage by changing opacity value greater than 0. see this http://jsfiddle.net/4JFpa/11/

Comment: Its better, cause window dosnt disapear at all, but there is no color transition animation. The background change the opacity to f.e. 0.4 and then then immediately change color. New background change the opacity from f.e 0.4 back to 1.